# -bash: __rvm_add_to_path: command not found

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04, ruby-on-rails, rvm

As soon as I log in to my server with ssh I get the message:

```
Last login: Wed Jul 17 16:13:07 2013 from foo.bar.net
-bash: __rvm_add_to_path: command not found
```

How can I fix that problem? My website is appearing correctly online but I'm trying to restart my server using:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

And I can't restart. Whenever I try to I get the message:

```
Starting httpd: [Wed Jul 17 16:19:11 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

I think if I can solve the rvm_add_to_path problem, I'll be able to restart ok. I can't understand why it's happening because when I last logged in with ssh 2 months ago everything was fine. (the only thing that's changed I can think of is that I've now given a domain name for my site, rather than the IP address) Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you are doing. So, this "server" hosts a webpage? What does ruby have to do with it? Is it a "normal" server or some kind of cloud based thing, Amazon or whatever? What makes you think it is not restarting? The message you get is just a warning. Check your `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` files for any mention of `__rvm_add_to_path`. Oh, and don't post real hostnames online, not a good idea.

Comment: The bash error and the log message are completely unrelated. The first one is related to some ruby management shell script while the other is due to the httpd (apache?) being misconfigured. So source the new (or old) ruby script and check your vhosts configuration.

Comment: Hi, yes, my server uses apache and my application is made with ruby on rails, using version 1.8.7. I'll look into your suggestions and get back to you, thanks.

Comment: @terdon - sorry, I forgot: I'm quite sure my server isn't restarting because there's no downtime. I click around my application while it's supposed to be restarting and there's no downtime at all. Is there somewhere I can check to see if it's restarted or not?